# IO.popen(my_cmd) - when is the subprocess done?

Tags: windows, ruby

```
pipe = IO.popen("my_cmd 2>&0")
while ???
  line = pipe.gets
  puts line if some_condition
end
```

This is using Ruby 1.8.7 on Windows.  `my_cmd` is an application that prints database records to the stdout.  One line per database record, and there's no way to know how many records there will be before I run the command.  Each `gets` call returns one record.  Each `gets` call could take a while, too.  It's going over a network to a very large database, so the gets call won't be instant.

I'm processing the input just fine.  The problem is, the loop never ends.

`my_cmd` terminates when it reaches the end of the database.  How does my Ruby script know when `my_cmd` is done?  What should `???` be in the code I posted above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
  while !out.eof?
```

or when you

```
 Process.wait pipe.pid
```

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Running_Multiple_Processes

Comment: This worked beautifully.  I swear I tried this already and it didn't work.  But now it does!